# In vagrant can not access to the default keystone site with nginx

Tags: nginx, vagrant, centos7, keystonejs

The vagrant server I configure with the following script still serve the default nginx page instead of the default keystone page.
Here the scripts I use:

The vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "mongodb-org-3.2.repo", destination: "~/mongodb-org-3.2.repo"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
end
```

The provision file:

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname melanie
echo "given hostname :"
hostnamectl status --static
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
add host names
***************************************************"

sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.origin
echo "192.168.1.10 melanie.misite.com melanie" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null
echo -e "\e[1;34mIP, FQDN and Server name setted in /etc/hosts:"
cat /etc/hosts
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
set timezone
***************************************************"

sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/Guayaquil
echo -e "\e[1;34msetted time zone:"
timedatectl | grep "Time zone"
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
add automatic security update
***************************************************"

sudo yum -y install yum-cron
sudo sed -i.bak 's/.*update_cmd =.*/update_cmd = security/' /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
sudo sed -i.bak 's/.*apply_updates =.*/apply_updates = yes/' /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
sudo sed -n /update_cmd/p /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
sudo sed -n /apply_updates/p /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
sudo systemctl status yum-cron
sudo systemctl start yum-cron
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
create limited user account
***************************************************"

sudo useradd me
sudo echo me:admin | chpasswd
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
SSH Dameon Options
***************************************************"

sudo sed -i.bak 's/.*PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo yum-cron.conf modified parameters:
sudo sed -n /PermitRootLogin/p /etc/ssh/sshd_config
systemctl restart sshd
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
installing fail2ban
***************************************************"


sleep 15 #put sleep hoping it will help to fail2ban to be installed => do not work
sudo yum -y install fail2ban
sudo yum -y install sendmail
sudo systemctl start fail2ban
sudo systemctl enable fail2ban
systemctl start sendmail
systemctl enable sendmail
cp /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.local
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sed 's/.*backend =*/backend = systemd./' /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
installing nginx
***************************************************"

sudo yum -y install epel-release 
sudo yum -y install nginx 
sudo systemctl start nginx
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
    configure nginx
***************************************************"

cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.backup
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-available
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo mkdir /var/www/misite.com/logs

sudo cp /home/vagrant/misite.conf /home/vagrant/misite.com
sudo mv /home/vagrant/misite.com /etc/nginx/sites-available > /dev/null
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/misite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www 
sudo service nginx restart > /dev/null
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
installing nodejs
***************************************************"

sudo yum -y install npm
sudo yum -y install nodejs
node --version
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
installing mongoDB
***************************************************"

sudo mv /home/vagrant/mongodb-org-3.2.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.2.repo
sudo yum -y install mongodb-org
systemctl start mongod
systemctl status mongod
echo -e "\e[1;34m

***************************************************
installing keystone
***************************************************"

sudo npm install -g yo
sudo mkdir /var/www
sudo mkdir /var/www/misite.com
cd /var/www/misite.com
sudo npm install -g generator-keystone
sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /var/www/
```

The nginx server conf file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/misite.com):
Here the keystone site should be redirect to the port 80 of the vagrant server **(I think the mistake is in this file but can not see where)**

```
# IP which nodejs is running on
upstream app_misite.com {
    server 0.0.0.0:3000;
}

# nginx server instance
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/www/misite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/misite.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/misite.com;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @node;
    }

    location @node {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://app_misite.com;
    }
}
```

I also remove the `default` keyword from the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Then:
    vagrant ssh
    [vagrant@melanie ~]$cd /var/www/misite.com
    [vagrant@melanie misite.com]$ yo keystone
    [vagrant@melanie misite.com]$ node keystone

And I have keystone js running:

```
------------------------------------------------
KeystoneJS Started:
My Site is ready on http://0.0.0.0:3000
------------------------------------------------
```

But still see the default nginx page from `http://192.168.1.10/`

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: I can access to the keystoneJs welcome page throught 192.168.1.10:3000 but no from 192.168.1.10:80

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Nginx, I'm trying to see if it may be settings with Keystone that are affecting the port it is running on versus Nginx.

Keystone defaults to port 3000 (more specifically, `process.env.PORT || 3000`), unless you specify another one. If you can set the environment variable of `port` to whatever value you want (80 in this case), that should make it work on http://192.168.1.10:80/.

```
process.env.PORT = 3000
```

Looking at your nginx server conf file also shows this:

```
upstream app_misite.com {
    server 0.0.0.0:3000;
}
```

Try changing `:3000` to `:80`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I d like to redirect the nodejs site. In order to have more nodejs site on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have cupple of issues :

1. nginx installed on centos has a default nginx.conf file with a `server` directive so you cannot override this directive in your config misite file.

You need to remove the `server` default declaration in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file or you can just use your provisioning script to copy a new default conf file without server declaration

I am also not even sure if the default file has an include directive on `sites-available` directory (look if you have `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in your conf file)

2. when you create the keystone app, it does not contain the `/var/www/misite.com/logs/` directory and log file, I do not see you create them in your script so nginx will fail on this (btw you can create a directory structure with `mkdir -pv` single command)
3. The keystone app you created is owned by vagrant. Make sure vagrant is added to `nginx` group otherwise you might get a Forbidden exception when accessing your site
4. can help on centos if you dont want to fight with SELinux, just disabled it on a dev instance. edit the `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and just set `SELINUX=disabled`

Comment: 1: I removed the default_server tags in the nginx.conf; 2 and 3: it s done by the script giving here.

Comment: 1: I comment all the server defined in nginx.conf but still the nginx welcome page appears

Comment: 2 is not done by your script - ssh into your VM and check if `/var/www/miste.com/logs/` exists; it will not, there's nowhere in your script from the question that you create such directory. 3. cannot be done by your script either as you say you run `yo` and `node keystone` after you ssh with `vagrant ssh` to your VM so you are logged in with vagrant for sure

Comment: 2: done in th part 'configure nginx': `sudo mkdir /var/www/misite.com/logs`. 3 sorry, I had done it manually. Vagrant was added to nginx group and then `sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/ `and `chmod 770 /var/www`